# How to import a CSV file in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse

I am trying to import a csv file that is in a folder called data on the same level as this function. I've tried to incorporate the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416529/react-import-csv-file-and-parse) I found on here, but no luck and I don't know what I need to modify.

[image]

**getData.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

export default function GetData(artist) {
    const data = Papa.parse(fetchCsv);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

async function fetchCsv() {
     const response = await fetch('data/artist_data.csv');
     const reader = response.body.getReader();
     const result = await reader.read();
     const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
     const csv = decoder.decode(result.value);
     return csv;
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769051/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-files-in-react-js

Comment: You will need import the csv to your project using some tool like some of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210467/adding-a-csv-file-to-a-webpack-build

then you can `import csv from 'data/artist_data.csv'`

Comment: You can also use csv-parse https://stackoverflow.com/a/72404267/343900

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Few problems I see here.**

1. When you do `fetch('data/mycsv.csv')` you are essentially making a request to `http://localhost:3000/data/mycsv.csv`. Check the n/w tab and you will see the response returned is your `html`. React first loads your root page and then checks further for routes.
2. Some coding errors like - you haven't called the `fetchCsv` fun inside `GetData` function. Also you need to await for `fetchCsv`.

**Solution:**

Move your `data` folder which has your csv file to the **public folder** and make corrections to your code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

async function GetData(artist) {
    const data = Papa.parse(await fetchCsv());
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

async function fetchCsv() {
    const response = await fetch('data/mycsv.csv');
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const result = await reader.read();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    const csv = await decoder.decode(result.value);
    console.log('csv', csv);
    return csv;
}
```

I have tested the above code in my local and it works fine.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked perfect and you answered questions that I was wondering too.