# Import csv file in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, csv, csv-import

In Angular a JSON file can be imported very easy with

```
import * as data from './mock.json';
```

when setting "resolveJsonModule" in tsconfig.json to `true`.

Is there a comparable functionality to import csv files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change angular's web-pack configs with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and then use something like [csv-loader](https://github.com/theplatapi/csv-loader)

Check out [Angular CLI: Custom webpack Config](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-webpack-config) for using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`, and also check out [Adding a csv file to a webpack build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210467/adding-a-csv-file-to-a-webpack-build)